# Issues with compiling Sencha Touch 2.4 and sencha-compass

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch

I would like to upgrade from Sencha Touch 2.3 to Sencha Touch 2.4

After doing:
`sencha app upgrade /sdk/touch-2.4.0`, I successfully upgraded my project.
However, when trying to build the project with: `sencha app build -run native` I get the following error with sencha-compass:

`executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["1"] of /resources/sass/common/_placeholders.scss: Invalid CSS after "": expected selector or at-rule, was "%txt-gray { col..."`

Compass-sass shows this:
`extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/sass-3.1.7/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:896:in 'expected'`

My project used to compile fine with Sencha Touch 2.3, but now it is not working. 
I think the problem is with using CSS placeholders in Sencha Touch 2.4. So my question is how to get CSS placeholders to work in Sencha Touch 2.4

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out  similar to this issue I had here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646687/sencha-touch-2-3-sass-mixin-breaks-sencha-app-build?rq=1

Comment: @jakeed1 thanks for the suggestion, but after trying that it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much time spent on this issue, I have realized that Sencha CMD does not need to recompile my scss files, and it is better for me to `compass watch` it myself.

In `.sencha/app/build.properties`

i added this line to skip sass: `skip.sass=true`

Now my app builds nicely with the Sencha Touch v2.4